# Polygon Intersection with Line | Python Shapely

Tags: python, line, polygon, intersection, shapely

I have been trying to use shapely to find the intersection of a line and a polygon, but I'm having issues with some floating point numbers.

Example code:

```
polygon = [(4.0, -2.0), (5.0, -2.0), (4.0, -3.0), (3.0, -3.0), (4.0, -2.0)]
shapely_poly = shapely.geometry.Polygon(polygon)

line = [(4.0, -2.0000000000000004), (2.0, -1.1102230246251565e-15)]
shapely_line = shapely.geometry.LineString(line)

intersection_line = list(shapely_poly.intersection(shapely_line).coords)
print intersection_line
```

What I would expect is a list of two vertices.

Point 1: point that would be inside the polygon, or (4.0, -2.0000000000000004) in this case.

Point 2: point that is the intersection of [(4.0, -2.0000000000000004), (2.0, -1.1102230246251565e-15)] and [(3.0, -3.0), (4.0, -2.0)].

However, the result I receive is:

```
[(4.0, -2.0000000000000004)]
```

I have also checked whether there is an intersection at all with the edge that I'm looking at:

```
>>> edge = shapely.geometry.LineString([(3.0, -3.0), (4.0, -2.0)])
>>> edge.intersects(shapely_line)
False
```

If I replace (4.0, -2.0000000000000004) with (4.0, -2.000000000000000) then the edge intersection will evaluate to True.

Does anyone have any ideas for what is going on or what I am missing? Thanks!

[image]

**Edit:**

I have tested using shapely version 1.12 and geos of 3.3.1, 3.3.5, 3.3.6, 3.3.7.

In case anyone is curious as to how I updated the geos version on Windows:

Downloaded the geos-[version].tar.bz2 from the GEOS website. Extracted the files and ran CMake on it, using the Visual Studio 10 Win64 generator. Opened the .sln file and built it then moved the generated geos_c.dll and pasted it over where geos_c.dll had been installed by shapely in the Python directory.

Comment: a picture would do this question a world of good

Comment: Thanks unutbu for the picture, it looks better than the one I was about to draw!

Comment: when I do `intersection = shapely_poly.intersection(shapely_line)` and then `print intersection` I get `LINESTRING (4.0000000000000000 -2.0000000000000004, 4.0000000000000000 -2.0000000000000000)`

Comment: Hmm that's weird, I get:
POINT (4.0000000000000000 -2.0000000000000004)

What version of python/shapely are you using? I'm using Shapely 1.1.14 and Python 2.7.3

Comment: Works fine for me on Ubuntu. Python 2.5.2, libgeos 3.3.5, Shapely version bit unsure (how do I find out?)

Comment: Shapely version 1.2.16, installed from an egg.

Comment: What version of GEOS.DLL do you have? Cause that is the one doing the heavy lifting.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check since I used the Windows installer (I just installed 1.2.16 and same issue). In my DLLs directory I see I have geos.dll and geos_c.dll which were last modified 5/26/2010. I have to go for now, but I'll investigate further since this may be the issue. Thank you for all the help so far!

Comment: I found two properties that you can print to see the respective versions: shapely.__version__ and shapely.geos.geos_version_string. The latter ought to be of interest.

Comment: it looks like a fun platform dependent robustness issue with GEOS and JTS (1.12, same answer on Win64)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shapely is built on top of a C wrapper around the C++ GEOS library. Somewhere [deep inside this C++ library](http://svn.osgeo.org/geos/trunk/src/precision/) sit the Precision classes which handle roundoff errors. I think we may conclude that your version of Shapely, and the geos libraries, handle this case differently. Unfortunately the code that accesses the precision model is not available in the C api, and therefore neither in Shapely.
See http://lists.gispython.org/pipermail/community/2011-February/002898.html

Changing to a higher version of geos might solve your issue, though. It works fine on my machine with shapely 1.2.16 and libgeos 3.3.5-CAPI-1.7.5.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the delay. The one it came packaged with was 3.3.1 and I tried using 3.3.5-CAPI-1.7.5, 3.3.6-CAPI-1.7.6, 3.3.7-CAPI-1.7.7 with no luck and running 1.12 Shapely. I'm thinking it's like Mike's response with the only other differenceI can think of being different is the platform.

Comment: Going to mark this as correct since in the end it seems to be something related to a difference in platforms anyways.

Comment: One last afterthought, do you have 32 bits or 64 bits machine / dlls?

Comment: I have a 64-bit machine, running 64-bit Python, 64-bit shapely, and compiled to x64 format for geos_c .dll

Comment: I tried using Ubuntu 12.10 with Python 2.7.3, Shapely 1.2.16, Geos 3.3.7 with no luck as well.

Comment: 32 bits here (i686), Ubuntu Hardy (8.0.4), Python 2.5. 32 bits would seem to be the relevant one, though counterintuitive?